# Best OCR for Xamarin Mvvmcross 4.4.0 ?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross, tesseract, xamarin-studio

i'm trying to use an OCR in Xamarin Mvvmcross 4.4.0 (not Xamarin.Forms) i want to avoid coding in platform specific. i've found [tesseract](https://github.com/halkar/Tesseract.Xamarin) but this library need coding in platform specific, i tried to inject with..

1.- SetUp.cs

```
protected override IMvxIocOptions CreateIocOptions()
        {
            return new MvxIocOptions() 
            {
                PropertyInjectorOptions = MvxPropertyInjectorOptions.MvxInject
            }; 
        }
```

2.- view model

```
[MvxInject]
        ITesseractApi _tesseract
        {
            get { 
                return Mvx.Resolve<ITesseractApi>(); 
                //return Mvx.IocConstruct<ITesseractApi>(); 
            }
        }
```

but both ( resolve, IocConstruct ) fail, 
if there's any idea or alternative ...

Comment: Did you inject `ITesseractApi` in MvvmCross IOC container?

Comment: i dont think so let me search how to do that

Comment: You can read about it here: [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/service-location-and-inversion-of-control)

Comment: Basically if you want IOC container to resolve your dependency you should first register it. For example you can do it like that: `Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IFoo>(new Foo());` IFoo will be added as singleton in this case.

Comment: i try this `Mvx.RegisterType<ITesseractApi, ITesseractApi>();` as i need it dynamic but i'm having the same issue there's no "TesseractApi" base class i only see the Interface in the PCL

Comment: I don't know the library but now your task is to find the way to create an instance of class that implements `ITesseractApi` and provides functionality you need. Again I don't know this library but according to their docs (github url that you have provided) it appears that you can create an object of `TesseractApi` and It has a parameterless constructor on iOS. I presume it implements `ITesseractApi`. So I would try `Mvx.RegisterSingleton< ITesseractApi >(new TesseractApi());` on iOS.

Comment: By the way, creation of `TesseractApi` and registration in IOC container should be done in platform specific (iOS, Android) projects not in your PCL. I suspect that is the reason way you don't `TesseractApi`.

Comment: yes but that's what i want to avoid, coding in IOS,Android. the question was to know if it was possible

Comment: Judging by their docs it is not possible to create an instance in shared code. `TesseractApi` is platform specific service. That means that it uses platform specific native api's on different platforms (notice Android constructor takes `Context` as an argument). Now `ITesseractApi` is an abstraction over it, so you can use it in your PCL. The only thing that you have to do in platform specific code is to create an instance and inject it in IOC. I recommend to investigate this approach because that is how a lot of services (including ones you write yourself) work in Xamarin.

Comment: Say that as answer so we close this ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to inject the dependencies to IOC container in order for it to be able to resolve them. You can do it like that in MvvmCross:

`Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IFoo>(new Foo());`

This registers dependency as singleton. You might or might not want to choose different lifetime. `Foo` is implementation of `IFoo` in this case.

You mentioned that you want to code your login in PCL. You can absolutely do just that by registering `ITesseractApi` dependency in platform specific projects (different instances of `ITesseractApi` on iOS and Android projects) and resolving it in your PCL. As far as I can tell from their docs, there is no way to create an instance of `TesseractApi` in shared code (notice Android constructor takes `Context` as an argument)

So your PCL will use different (platform specific) code on different platforms trough an abstraction of `ITesseractApi`.